# What's the katakana for the 'down' in kabedown instead of kabedon that Miyuki Shirogane 'invented'?

Tags: japanese-language, kaguya-sama-love-is-war

S01E02 Miyuki gives advice to Tsubasa Tanuma. Part of the advice includes the 'kabe-down', an original invention of Miyuki.

[image]

Wait no actually as Kaguya points out it's something that's been around forever, and it's called kabedon (壁ドン [かべドン]).

[image]

This particular translation of 'kabedon' is 'wall slam'. [I read on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%81%E3%83%89%E3%83%B3) that don (ドン) is actually literally an onomatopoeia (hence why katakana instead of hiragana or kanji is used I guess), but whatever.] Ok so what's the katakana (or hiragana/kanji?) for the 'down' in 'kabedown' ? Is it just ダウン (daun)?  But in this case why is ダウン = slap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ダァン (e.g. [source](https://twitter.com/jvr2nnhje2mwjnp/status/1293364996311670786)), which is an onomatopoeia similar to ドン. The difference is, ダァン is a prolonged sound and as such a bit stronger. Possibly a better comparison would be the other way around: ダァン/ドン = Slam/Slap, but *slam* seems already taken, hence the current translation (*slap* would be too weak for either anyway, I suppose). Here you can think ダァン is used simply because the author wanted the same thing as ダン but slightly different.

In general, difference of using hiragana/katakana for onomatopoeia is rather subtle. Although I don't think authors use them with much intention, looking at the [One Piece usage of どーん](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%20%E3%81%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%93&rlz=1C1AVNE_enJP724JP725&sxsrf=APq-WBsFSDN-bEvHb_y6nNBG-OQjUGfyTg:1649893688389&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrdr5nJL3AhVlJaYKHWunB9gQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1565&bih=801&dpr=1.1), hiragana is used for 'effect sound' and katakana for the actual sound (cannon, guns etc.). The ダァン is consistent with this.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement sundowner's answer:

1. The live action seems to confirm this as kabedaan (壁ダァン).

[image]

2. Just search ダァン in google. Like you don't have to search 壁ダァン. Just ダァン is enough. Lol.